# Curl не парсит динамично сайт?

Tags: php, http, curl

Здравствуйте, написал curl для граббера сайта, но на сайте где нужно парсить пустая страница, с других сайтов берет. В чем проблема ?

```
        $url = 'http://www.betsbc.com/v3/ru/';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo $content;
```

Comment: Возможно вас блокирую, часто запросы отправляете...

Comment: @Arsen не похоже, скорее всего защита какая-то стоит

Comment: посмотрел ссылку, а вы смотрели ?? там же контент через ajax подгружается... понятно что пустая страница будет для CURL ) source страницы откройте

Comment: @Arsen есть ведь какие-то варианты брать части сайта ?

Comment: да могут быть, надо хорошо проанализировать как работает сайт.... можно и найти кроличью нору..

Comment: @Arsen Имитация экрана ведь не подойдет ? Можно ли подобное на js сделать ?

Comment: нет имитация не поможет, просто пример привести не получится, многое что надо испробовать )

Comment: смотрите куда аякс-запросы идут, и оттуда данные берите.

Comment: В браузере можно включить трассировку аякс запросов и увидеть, что получает json по запросам вида http://www.betsbc.com/api/v1/live/bets?rev=6&ids=4126854&stat=1&md=1504208759&ver=149&csn=f9xg7b осталось понять, какие параметры отсылает, что получает и самому послать такой запрос

Comment: Ещё можно через phantomjs попробовать